# Learning AVR XMEGA

Tags: avr, xmega

I am trying to learn how to program the AVR XMEGA by using the XMEGA-A1 Xplained kit with a JTAGICE3 programmer. I am going through the Xmega Basics pdf ([link](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8398.pdf)).

In one of the instructions I am told to open I/O view for the LED port and look at the registers. I should see something like this:

[image]

Instead my I/O window looks like this. I get no PORTLED (which is defined in the board.h file). And my PORTE (where the LEDs are located) doesn't carry any information.

[image]

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if you just don't have that column turned on?

Comment: How do I check this?

Comment: Right-click on the column headers, see if there is a way to change or modify them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a fresh install of Atmel Studio the view registers pane is off by default, it's the second button in the IO View window and I can see in your screen shot it's turned off. This was with a different ATxmega attached so the registers are different but it looks as follows once enabled:

[image]